# Call MdiParent Method on Ctrl+S of MdiChild form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an mdiParent form in which i have a save method. Now I want that whenever i press Ctrl+S in my activeMdiChild form the parents Save method should get called. Any hint or suggestion is welcome.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Create a Static Object of MDI parent and use it in child form....

Comment: You don't need to pass an instance of parent or creating some static properties. You can simply get the key combination using `ProcessCmdKey` of `MDI` parent. Also using a `MenuStrip` will help you to get the job done simply by setting a short cut for a menu.

Comment: Actually i found out the solution that you mentioned earlier. But +1 for your help.

Comment: Okie dokie.. No worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a MenuStrip in the MDI Parent Form, then you don't need to do anything else than adding a menu with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> shortcut. Then if the user press those combination even in child form, the code for that menu of parent will execute.

But if you don't want to add a menu, then you can override `ProcessCmdKey` in the "MDI Parent Form" and check if the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> combination was pressed, then perform the desired action:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.S))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Handled in main form.");
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

> The
>   [`ProcessCmdKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey(v=vs.110).aspx)
>   method overrides the base `ContainerControl.ProcessCmdKey`
>   implementation to provide additional handling of main menu command
>   keys and MDI accelerators.

Answer (score 1):

Handle the `KeyDown` event in `activeMdiChild` .

```
private void activeMdiChild _KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
        {
          dynamic parent = this.Parent;
          parent.Save();
        } 
}
```

EDIT: as mentioned in comments, `mdiParent.Save` must be public

Comment: @Murtaza Munshi, this will work for you, your parent Save function should be public

Comment: @Murtaza Munshi,make sure save is public

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions: 
 1. Create an interface 
`ISave
 {
  void Save();
 }`
 2. Let your parent form inherit interface
 3. In your child form check for ctrl + s if so do 
 `ISave saver = this.Parent as ISave;
 if(saver != null)
    saver.Save();`
That's all

Comment: I have implemented an interface in all child forms. So i want Parent form to detect Ctrl+S & then call child forms Interface Save Method.

Comment: Do i that way: Child -> `Parent.Save()` -> `foreach(child in Childs) child.Save();`